# Why does adding a subsurf modifier cause top face to stay flat?

Tags: subdivision-surface

My very new to blender not sure what is going on. I'm yet to round of the corners as it doesn't seem to affect the main edge. Here's my current model

[image]

Screen shot of the other side

[image]

But once I add the subdivision modifier it doesn't work on the top face but does on everything else. I've also made sure to make everything 4 points but that doesn't seem to help.

[image]

[image]

What would you suggest to improve my model? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hello and welcome. Can you share your blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: *"What would you suggest to improve my model?"* - **A, M, B** keys (select all, merge by distance)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have an interior face in there. Go into X-ray mode and delete it if that's the case
[image]